# Which space project was remained as most postponed in space history?

Tags: history, james-webb-telescope

I am asking this question before few hours to launch of [JWST space telescope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope).

This many times [JWST space telescope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope) was postponed:

- Early 2019: planned launch date as of October 2017.
- May 2020 or later: planned launch date as of March 2018.
- March 30, 2021: planned launch date as of June 2018.
- October 31, 2021: planned launch date as of July 2020.
- November 2021 or later: planned launch date as of June 2021.
- December 22, 2021: planned launch date as of November 2021.
- December 24, 2021: planned launch date after delay due to communication issues between the observatory and the Launch Vehicle.
- December 25, 2021: planned launch date after delay due to forecasts of unfavorable weather during the launch window on the 24th.

Above data collected from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_James_Webb_Space_Telescope#Pre-launch_plans).

Comment: You missed many delays in that list of yours. The original project began in 1996, for a launch in 2007. Not that **anyone** expected that schedule to happen, but that was the original plan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know *how many* times it was postponed, but I'm pretty sure the record for *longest* time postponed belongs to [Gravity Probe B](https://einstein.stanford.edu/), which got its first funds from NASA in [1963](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/gpb/gpb_results.html), launched in [2004](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/gpb/index.html), and presented results in [2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3456).

Comment: Have you corrected that 48 delay for GR effects?

Comment: And don't forget the leap seconds! ;)

Comment: @nealmcb mid-year leap seconds were the bane of my existence.  i lost days of work in 2012 to that damn second.  we should just eliminate them, or else postpone them all until we do a whole leap hour in about 5 thousand years.